# 1995 VM Jetta/Vento - ECU pinout for my car

Tags: vw, electronic-control-module, fuel-injection, electronics

I own a 95 Vento GL (Jetta for the american market), with an 1.8 8v, 90hp ADD model engine. The ECU for this model is marked with part number `037 906 021A`.

I have checked with VAG-COM software and it shows a code `00532` that says "Supply voltage B+". This means the car has a bad grounding issue, that may be causing problems with fuel economy and hesitation.

Recently I have changed my lambda sensor because the car is black smoking and idles very bad, and when I came to unplug the old sensor I found out that a black wire was broke, but I couldn't find the other part.

I followed to the ECU and found that from the same terminal comes a red wire, but I couldn't determine where it goes.

Does anyone has a pin diagram of the ECU so I can check out and confirm that this black wire is the ground that is missing?